# Identifying datatype of a column in an SQLite Android Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there any way to identify the datatype of a column in a cursor in Android. The cursor object has a number of methods to get the columnname, column value.

I want to find out the SQLite datatype of the column (TEXT, INTEGER) etc...

I'm writing a generic function to parse a cursor and perform operations. I will only get a sql string as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the SQLite documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) columns in SQLite don't have a datatype -- the values in those columns do.

> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.

If you're using API level 11 or above then the cursor supports `getType()` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractWindowedCursor.html#getType(int)).

If you're using an earlier API level, and you know that all the results in a given cursor come from the same table then you could do something like (untested):

```
// Assumes "cursor" is a variable that contains the cursor you're
// interested in.

String tableName = "..."; // The name of the table
SQLiteDatabase db = cursor.getDatabase();
String[] names = cursor.getColumnNames();

for (name : names) {
    Cursor typeCursor = 
        db.rawQuery("select typeof (" + name + ") from " + tableName;
    typeCursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.v("test", "Type of " + name + " is " + typeCursor.getString(0);
}
```

But that will (I expect) fail if the passed in cursor was (for instance) the result of a db.rawQuery() call that joined two or more tables.

Comment: Thanks Nik, that was a pretty neat idea. But do you think using JDBC's Resultset could also be used? I have been reading that JDBC is not supported by Google.

Comment: Possibly -- I don't have a definitive answer I'm afraid.  However, you're still tackling this from the wrong end.  As I said, SQLite columns don't really have data types, it's the value in the column that has the type.

So you could have three rows and a column "foo", and in row 1 the contents look like text, in row 2 they look like an int, and in row 3 the contents look like a binary blob.  The data type of the column won't help.

Perhaps you could amend your question with more information about what you're actually trying to achieve and I can suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896348/to-get-resultset-from-pre-complie-statement-in-android/7270433#7270433 for more info about this.

Comment: _columns in SQLite don't have a datatype_ of course he meant about values of column ... not column itself....

Answer (score 6):

The answer or NiK, is fine. But if your db is empty, his code crashes.
I suggest use:

```
String Query = "PRAGMA table_info(my_table_name)"; 
Cursor my_cursor  = db.rawQuery(Query, null); 
my_cursor.moveToFirst();
Column_name = my_cursor.getString(my_cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
Column_type = my_cursor.getString(my_cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
```

Answer (score 5):

I didn't tested yet but, try to use cursor.getType(i)

Like this:

```
public static List resultSetToArrayListAndroid(Cursor cursor) throws SQLException {
    int columns = cursor.getColumnCount();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
            switch (cursor.getType(i))  {
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                    row.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getFloat(i));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                    row.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getInt(i));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                    row.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                    break;
            }
        }
        list.add(row);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [meta data](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) from sqlite Database :

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html

You get this item by using getMetaData() on a ResultSet().

So, it's not the usual way of using a sqlite database in android that you shall use, but the usual JDBC way :

1. get a connection (through driver manager getConnection)
2. get a statement (through connection.createStatement)
3. get a resultset  (through statement.executeQuery)
4. get the meta data (through resultset.getMetaData)

Regards,
Stéphane

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, I'm currently using a Android cursor object (android.database.cursor) which is returned from SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery method. What procedure should I use to get a ResultSet. Been searching, but not finding a way to connect to the database and obtain a resultset.

Comment: String url = "jdbc:sqlite:/data/data/app.name/databases/Database";
Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
con.close();

Comment: But I have read that  JDBC is not supported by Google. Is it advisable to use JDBC or the built in android.sqlite object?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a toList extension function for Cursor:

```
fun Cursor.toList(): List<List<Any>> {
    fun getValues(cursor: Cursor, numberOfFields: Int): List<Any> {
        return (0 until numberOfFields).map { index ->
            when {
                cursor.getType(index) == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING -> {
                    cursor.getString(index)
                }
                cursor.getType(index) == Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER -> {
                    cursor.getInt(index)
                }
                else -> {
                    throw Exception("Unknown type when trying to get value at cursor.")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val list = generateSequence { if (this.moveToNext()) this else null }
        .map {
            getValues(it, this.columnCount)
        }
        .toList()
    return list
}
```

Call like this:

```
val results: List<List<Any>> = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tableName", null).toList()
val firstResult = results[0]
val firstResultsFirstValue = firstResult[0]
```

Make sure to set your actual table name in the query and add more types to the when function as needed.