# How do I copy the contents of a cursor?

Tags: android

What is the easiest way to copy the contents from one cursor to another (make a deep copy)?

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

    // I want to make a deep copy of the cursor here.
}
```

Comment: Um, iterate over the contents and build up a `MatrixCursor`, I guess. Why do you feel that you need a copy of a `Cursor`? Usually, if you are going to copy data from a `Cursor`, it is to build up a list of POJOs or something.

Comment: onLoadFinished gets called multiple times by the OS (no rotation of the device) for some reason (some threads say its a bug in Android). The widely popular solution is to `getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(int id)` it, but when I do that, the adapter that uses the cursor data crashes with an exception for an already closed cursor, or a NPE, can't remember. So I want to kill the loader but I want to keep the cursor.

Comment: I havent written the code that I am working on, and the adapter is really tightly coupled to the image cursor. I hate loaders. I guess I should convert the cursor to POJOs then I should kill the loader, but I was thinking maybe just deep copying it would require a change in only one place in the code. But I don;t know how to do that

Comment: "I hate loaders" -- then don't use them.

Comment: I don't... but I don't want to rewrite the entire class...

Comment: Had the loader got a registered listener that delivers a cursor when the underlying data changes? If so converting to POJO's could result in a Race Condition where you're still processing the cursor, however if the data changes, it will be closed by a background thread, and try to deliver a new cursor .. I do agree view logic should not be tightly coupled with databases ..

Comment: "onLoadFinished gets called multiple times" is this in a fragment inside a viewpager? or an activity with multiple fragments?

Comment: Activity that loads thumbnail paths from the media store and displays them in a grid. This only happens the first time ever, then all the following loads happen flawlessly, even if I reinstall the app.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178319/how-to-clone-or-freeze-an-android-database-cursor