# Android SQLite long value being retrieved/cast as an int value

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an `INTEGER` column in my database table and have saved the value of `1476355625598` to it (by updating an existing row).

When I immediately check the value by doing a query, I get the same, correct, value of `1476355625598` returned.

However, when my IntentService later retrieves the value, it is getting the value of `-1113124226` returned.

I've done a check and `-1113124226` is the same value as if you'd called `(int)1476355625598`.

I've added debugging output to all my lines of code that modify this column, and can confirm that I have no other database operations that are updating the value.

So it seems something is casting my long to an int... Any ideas how/why this could be happening?

NB - The value I'm saving is a timestamp (millis format), which is preferable to saving it in a String format.

**UPDATE**

Because my database is accessible via a content provider, I've added a content observer to my MyApplication class. It does not report any other updates of the table in question.

**UPDATE #2**

Issue now solved. See comment...

Comment: How do you retrieve the value from the database ? You do tried to get long value ? I would guess that you (or the system used) use the getter of Integer on the Cursor.

Comment: Thanks, AxelH, but I've just found the problem. The issue was that I had cloned the cursor incorrectly based on this (now updated) code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40008872/1617737 . Too many late nights... :-/

Comment: Indeed, you used getInt for INTEGER type but you said yourself that this can store a Long. SQlite use some strange type name ...

Comment: Yeah, I definitely fell down a trap with that one! It was only when stepping into my `cursor.getLong(...)` method with the debugger that I realised the cursor was (incorrectly) cloned. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP find his error before I have the time to write this but I will still post it to close it. OP can add his own if he want (no hard feeling ;) ) (This will prevent others to spam later to get some rep point...)

As excepted, the problem was coming from the retrieving of the value from the cursor. Even if the value is store into an INTEGER, this column can hold a `long` so on the cursor, we need to get the value using the `getLong(int)` or `getLong(String)` methods. If not, JAVA will truncate the value as excepted.

In the question, the getter is not present but the OP post and answer on an other POST : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008872/1617737

This show how he duplicate a cursor. This was were he used `getInt` instead of `getLong` for NUMERIC SqliteType.

Answer (score 0):

use this

`long id = cursor.getLong(colIndex);`

instead of

`long id = cursor.getint(colIndex);`

Comment: Thanks, but that's what AxelH already said in his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40022593/1617737