# Is it possible to have a generic bulk insert statement?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have an database import process where I have a list of files which correspond to tables. The files are simple csv text files filled with data.

I would like to speed up the data import by using bulk inserts, so I have the following method:

```
private void bulkInsert(String tableName) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO "+ tableName +" VALUES (?,?,?);";
    SQLiteStatement statement = sampleDB.compileStatement(sql);
    sampleDB.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindLong(1, i);
        statement.bindLong(2, i);
        statement.bindLong(3, i*i);
        statement.execute();
    }
    sampleDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
    sampleDB.endTransaction();
}
```

The above method is not the method I'm currently using. In the method. I have 3 columns of type `long`.

However, as I have different tables with columns of different data types, is it possible generalize the above method? Maybe iterate through the columns and get the type?

**EDIT**

Would `bindAllArgsAsStrings` work? The data stored in the columns might be `text`, `integer` or `real`. I might also have `NULL` values in the data.

Comment: there's this method `bindAllArgsAsStrings` accept arrays as parameters.

Comment: Why you are trying to make single method more complicated by adding multiple logic in same method instead of creating seprate methods for inserting different type of data?

Comment: See following post probably help :[Indentifying datatype of a column in an SQLite Android Cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293063/indentifying-datatype-of-a-column-in-an-sqlite-android-cursor)