# Get DataType instead of Storage Class from Sqlite Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to be able to retrieve the data type of a returned column as per the data type stated at the CREATE statement, so the data can be cast/processed accordingly into objects.

I understand that SQLite does not use a static type system. `PRAGMA table_info(table_name)` returns the information I am interested in, which means it is not lost after table creation. Taking into account that `Cursor.getType()` returns the storage class, I am wondering if there is any other method that can give me the data type. That doesn't have to be in the `android.database.Cursor`. It can be any class library with similar functionality.

If such a thing is not possible, which route would you suggest to follow:

1. Create a parser for the sql query and obtain the columns and get the datatype from maps held in static objects?
2. Assign a prefix at the beginning of each value inserted in the database which will signify the data type and will be stripped off during reads?

Comment: check this answer out [Indentifying datatype of a column in an SQLite Android Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293063/indentifying-datatype-of-a-column-in-an-sqlite-android-cursor )

Comment: Some part of your app knows what type it wrote into the columns used in the query. You should reorganize it so that this information is not lost.