# Create method which returns resultset from sql query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, resultset

I have a little problem with creating a method which takes `String` as parameter and return ResultSet after execute the query.Here is an example actually what I'm trying to do :

```
public ResultSet executeSQLQuery(String query){
        ResultSet rs = sqliteDb.rawQuery(query,null);;
        return rs;
    }
```

Something like this, but it says that I have to convert rs to cursor type, but I need to return RS. Any ideas how to get the things to work?

Answer (score 1):

```
possible duplicate
```

The result set isn't available, at least for now, in sqlite. It all depends on exactly what information you want from the ResultSet or ResultSetMetaData, etc, but there are other means of obtaining almost the same information.

check this link

[to get resultset from pre-complie statement in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896348/to-get-resultset-from-pre-complie-statement-in-android/7270433#7270433)